# Gravar somente um campo no banco de dados

Tags: java, sql

Como faço pra gravar somente um dos campos desse `select`?

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet RS = null;
RS = stmt.executeQuery("select codplpag, descricao from pcplpag ORDER BY 1,2"); 

while(RS.next()){  
    //  ListaBox.addItem(RS.getString("codplpag")+" / " + RS.getString("descricao"));
    ListaBox.addItem(RS.getString("codplpag" )+" / " + RS.getString("descricao"));
}
```

Update:

```
int registro = stmt.executeUpdate("update pcpedc set codplpag =" +ListaBox.getSelectedItem().toString()+ 
                    "where numped=" + consPCPEDC);
```

Comment: Falta um espaço antes do WHERE, será que é só isso?

Comment: pior que não @bfavaretto, ele me traz o item selecionado e tudo mais, amis quando eu boto pra salvar ele salva a descrição junto com o numero "codplpag"+ a descrição "descricao" ai ele da erro

Comment: A melhor coisa que você pode fazer é usar `PreparedStatement` e evitar criar sua *query* concatenando variáveis.

Comment: Meu conselho seria não usar duas informações distintas como um item do `ListBox`. Mas se quiser insistir nisso você teria que separar os dois dados para usar só o que interessa. Esse `codplpag` tem tamanho fixo garantido? Qual é?

Comment: tem o tamanho de 2 campos

Comment: como eu faço pra separar os dados?

Comment: Você pode obter uma substring do item selecionado, pegando os primeiros caracteres ou contando com o separador que você usou (" / "). Mas pode ficar melhor que isso. Qual é o tipo/classe de `ListaBox`?

Comment: O que é tamanho de 2 campos? Seria 2 caracteres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu recomendaria você não juntar duas informações em um item do `ListBox`. Mas se quer insistir nisto dá para ter uma solução.

Se não souber o tamanho do campo pode fazer isto:

```
String codPlPag = ListaBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
int posicaoBarra = codPlPag.indexOf(" /");
if(posicaoBarra != -1){
    int registro = stmt.executeUpdate("update pcpedc set codplpag ='" + 
                       codPlPag.substring(0, posicaoBarra) + "' where numped=" + consPCPEDC);
} else {
    //deu erro
}
```

Tentei pegar só a parte que interessa e arrumei o problema da falta de aspas e falta de espaço antes do `where` denunciado pelo bfavaretto.

Tenho minhas dúvidas se o `consPCPEDC` também não precisa de aspas. Em condições normais deveria.

Se souber o tamanho, se for 2 caracteres garantido, pode fazer mais simples:

```
String codPlPag = ListaBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
int registro = stmt.executeUpdate("update pcpedc set codplpag ='" + 
                       codPlPag.substring(0, 2) + "' where numped=" + consPCPEDC);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/ReplaceSubstring.java).

Note que isto que está fazendo é perigoso e inseguro, não faça.

Comment: cara muito bom eu realmente ia ficar morrendo nesse treco muito obrigado. abraço